# How to access a list from the net and show the list as an list control on the Device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to create a list control from a csv/txt file which I have hosted on my site, The CSV/txt can be edited to add new items(in rows) every row has 4 coloumns,

This file should be downloaded first time the app runs, and can be updated later.

I want the list to feature like this:

Title-(1st Coloumn of the row)
Subtitle-(2nd coloumn of the row)

And when the user clicks the list item a page opens which displays all the 4 items in that separate page. I also want that list to be searcheable wrt the 1st item.

Comment: Inception was easier to understand !

Comment: What did you do so far, are you stuck anywhere?

Comment: I have created the file to upload,

I can't understand how to link that data in the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the file, parse it, display as a list, make the displayed list items clickable with clicks triggering navigation to the details view of your collection item and have a search box, right?

1. To download the file - you could use WebClient.DownloadStringAsync
2. To parse it - you could use string.Split('\n') and string.Split(',')
3. To display as list - you would put the parsed objects representing csv file rows in a collection - like a List, then use a ListBox control and set its ItemsSource to that list. Additionally you would need to define the ItemTemplate to display the strings in two columns, eg.

   ```
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <!-- The DataContext here is a string array, so binding to [i] will bind to its string at position i -->
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0]}" Width="240" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding [1]}" Width="240" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   ```
4. To handle clicks - the best way would be to use Buttons with Command-bindings, but the simple solution works OK too - you just handle ListBox.SelectionChanged event and the SelectedItem is what was clicked - you have to override OnNavigated in your page and set ListBox.SelectedItem back to null when you navigate back there to allow clicking the same item again.
5. To navigate to another page with all the details - you can call NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/DetailsPage.xaml?col1={0}&col2={1}&col3={2}&col4={3}", Uri.EscapeUriString(((string[])(lb.SelectedItem))[0]), ... [1,2,3]), UriKind.Relative), then parse the Uri in OnNavigatedTo override of the DetailsPage class.
6. To allow searches in the ListBox you would use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) object as the ItemsSource of the ListBox and allow the user to enter [search](http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/14/wp7-in-app-searching-filtering.html) queries that would update the Filter causing the contents of the ListBox to refresh.

Comment: I can't get this to work.
I cannot convert the downloaded file to a list.
Plz help me with some code.
I am a newbie in software developing.

Comment: What do you get in the downloaded file?

Comment: it is a csv.
which have 4 coloumns and many rows.
Rows can be added in the remote file,
So that app does not have to be updated every time.

Comment: Then as I said - you get a string when you download it and call string.Split('\n') to get an array of lines and then for each line line.Split(',') will separate the columns separated by commas into an array of fields.

Comment: plz explain the pasing into list and search with code.
I will be highly greatful.